Problem Calling Youtube upload API from AWS Lambda Async Function
Hi New to nodejs here.
I am trying to upload youtube videos using GoogleApls SDK. The problem is the SDK method supports callback function. Buy My AWS lambda is an async event handler and I cant change it . Hence the callback is never called. How can this be solved?
service.videos.insert({
            auth: auth,
            part: 'snippet,status',
            requestBody: {
                snippet: {
                    title,
                    description,
                    tags,
                    categoryId: categoryIds.ScienceTechnology,
                    defaultLanguage: 'en',
                    defaultAudioLanguage: 'en'
                },
                status: {
                    privacyStatus: "private"
                },
            },
            media: {
                body: stream,
            },
        }, function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                err;
            }
            console.log(response.data)
            response.data;
        });

EDIT as per @Bergis comment the youtube api does not support async await based on what i see in the doc.

Are you sure that it supports only callback functions? https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client?tab=readme-ov-file#using-the-client-library suggests you can just use const response = await service.videos.insert({ auth: auth, part: 'snippet,status', requestBody: …, media: …, });

@Bergi thanks for commenting based in what I see the youtube API does support Async await.  I followed this tute: https://quanticdev.com/articles/automating-my-youtube-uploads-using-nodejs/.   Btw I dont see Videos.Insert example in the link you gave?

As far as I can tell, that part of the readme covers all methods in the API, not just the one they used as an example.
